# How to reshape in Python by preserving structure of matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to make a transformation that I thought to be trivial but I am not able to find any solution to this. I have an array of dimensions (3, 3, 2), such as the following one:

```
array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]],
[[7,8], [9,0], [1,2]],
[[3,4], [5,6], [7,8]])
```

I would like to transform it to a (2, 3, 3) array of the following form

```
array([[1, 3, 5],
[7, 9, 1],
[3, 5, 7]],
[[2, 4, 6],
[8, 0, 2],
[4, 6, 8]])
```

such that each matrix of this array contains all the elements of the respective indices for each tuple in the first matrix. Is there any way to do this, either with NumPy or preprocessing tools of ML libraries? In a sense this operation corresponds to "decoupling" the channels of an image in two separate matrix.

Comment: Swapaxes or transpose.  Read the docs and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user **hpaulj**, the operations needed to do this were `np.swapaxes(A, 0, 2).transpose(0,2,1)` if `A` was the original array.

As explained in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html), `swapaxes` interchanges the two axes of a multidimensional array. This leaves the submatrices in a transposed form with respect to the one we want, so we should transpose the array in such a way to preserve the order of the array containing the submatrices and transposing *only* the submatrices themselves.